# Link the static system library libm.a in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries, codeblocks, libm

I successfully compile my program in the shell with the command below. It produces the example binary file and works normally.

```
gcc -g -o build/debug/example -Iinclude docs/example.c \
build/debug/libmupdf.a \
build/debug/libfreetype.a build/debug/libjbig2dec.a \
build/debug/libjpeg.a build/debug/libopenjpeg.a \
build/debug/libz.a -lm
```

However, it doesn't work if I try to compile in Code::Blocks. The project build options look like this:

[image: Project build options]
The compiler gives one error:

```
more undefined references to 'FT_Name_Index' Fellow
```

I think I made a mistake while linking the static system library `libm.a`. How can I link it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it like this
[image]

use the command int the other linker option directly